# what does “toolkit independent web framework” mean?

Tags: web-development

Well .. I am new to web development and I want to know what does toolkit independent framework mean?

Comment: Cross posted on Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604660/what-does-toolkit-independent-web-framework-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major types of software libraries: frameworks and toolkits (component libraries). A framework provides architecture, a toolkit provides functionality.

Most frameworks out there come bundled with their own toolkits. There's even some so-called 'frameworks' that are basically just toolkits and the only architecture they provide is intended to make the included components work together.

A toolkit independent framework is a framework that doesn't *depend* on a specific toolkit, i.e. you can use it with a number of (framework independent) toolkits.
An example would be an MVC-framework, that lets you choose your own GUI-component library (although I haven't actually seen a good example of this).

Comment: Well, what about using something like django with GWT?

Comment: @Federico Culloca: Well, that's a way to look at it, since there is a number of solutions, that span server and client side and are not particularly open to substitution of their bundled components with 3rd party ones. I don't know django well enough to judge, whether it can be considered toolkit independent within the scope of the server side itself, however.

Answer (score 2):

The only [Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22toolkit%20independent%20web%20framework%22) for the phrase "toolkit independent web framework" are for this very question.

So, given that you apparently coined the phrase yourself, how about *you* tell *us* what it means?

Comment: Aha. Well, given that the word "toolkit-independent" is a response in the "AJAX" column, and looking at the other possibilities, I would say it means that these frameworks provide the necessary back-end support for AJAX requests, but don't provide their own specific front-end implementation, nor are they tied to a specific existing toolkit, such as jQuery.